# Infinite summation question and i need to make an algorithm for finding the summation?

Tags: summation, computational-mathematics, math-software

> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {x^{2n -1}} {2n!}$$

for the algorithm i use == $d=\frac {a_{n}} {a_n - 1}$

And other hint that I have is the for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {x^{2n}} {n!}$ ; $d = \frac{x}{n} $

So my question is that what will be `d = ?` for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {x^{2n -1}} {2n!}$

Comment: Do you really mean $2n!$ and not $(2n)!?$ With $(2n)!$ the solution is in terms of Struve functions
$$\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{x}}\mathbf{L}\left(\frac{1}{2},x\right)$$

Comment: $\frac 12\frac{1-e^{x^2}}{x}$

Comment: @Cesareo: You should change the sign of the expression. The function is positive for $x>0.$

Comment: its `2n!` not `(2n)!`

Comment: @gammatester Thanks! Now is  too late to edit the hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want a recursive relation for your algorithm or a similar thing, so perhaps
$$d=\dfrac{a_{n}}{a_{n-1}}=\dfrac{x^2}{n}$$
works, or want to have $d=s_{k}-s_{k-1}=\dfrac{x^{2k-1}}{2k!}$ where
$$s_k=\sum_{n=1}^{k} \frac {x^{2n -1}} {2n!}$$
is partial sum of the series. In such case the relation is
$$s_{k}=\dfrac{x^{2k-1}}{2k!}+s_{k-1}$$
where $s_1=\dfrac{x}{2}$.

Comment: Yes i wanted that $\frac{x}{2} $

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the sum with the exponential function:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {x^{2n -1}} {2n!}
=\frac{1}{2x}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {x^{2n}} {n!}
=\frac{1}{2x}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {(x^2)^n} {n!}
= \frac{e^{x^2}-1}{2x}$$
here used the well-known formula for 
$e^y = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {y^n} {n!}$and therefore
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {y^n} {n!} = e^y -1$$

Comment: where does the `n` go ? There is no value of `n`

Comment: @user83869: See edit.

Comment: But I want a simple answer like that of `x \ n` . As mentioned above in the question

Comment: There is no $n$ in the answer, because it is the summation index. Your $d$ would be $\frac{x^2}{n}$